# Are the Borg defeated?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

I just watched *Star Trek: First Contact* again, and then I reflected back on Voyager. What's going on there? Are the Borg gone? Is the Queen finally dead, or is she forever lurking?

Comment: And, if so, is Captain Picard the last Borg?

Comment: The answer to your non-question comment is "No. Picard is no more Borg than Seven of Nine, and probably less."

Comment: looking for film / series canon only? The books provide an answer in the *excellent* Star Trek: Destiny trilogy, which, even if you don't want that as an answer, I'd highly recommend reading. As much as the newer books can, they attempt to stay consistent with one another and film / television canon. Destiny is post-Nemesis

Comment: Looks like this question is going to get some love after Star Trek: Picard airs :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only a handful of major Star Trek stories that have taken place after the the last episode of Voyager (*Endgame*):

- **Star Trek: Nemesis** - No Borg
- **Star Trek: Countdown** - This was a canon comic book mini-series published as a lead-in to the 2009 Star Trek reboot. It takes place in 2387, 9 years after *Endgame*. In it, you see the supernovas endangering Romulan Empire and the efforts of Spock to use the red matter to help solve the problem. In particular, the Romulans enhance the Nerada (Nero's ship) with Borg technology, implying that, at the least, some Borg technology remained functional even after the deployment of the neurolytic pathogen. [image]
- **Star Trek Online** - This MMORPG takes place in the prime timeline in 2409, 22 years after the destruction of Romulus. One of several storylines is the Borg reappearing after more than 30 years of quiet post-*Endgame*.

So how you answer the question depends on how you interpret the canonicity of Countdown and Online.

Comment: just curious - what is the canonicity of ST: Online? More or less than the current crop of books?

Comment: Nice answer.  You should remove *Insurrection* though.  It doesn't occur after the last episode of *Voyager*.  It went to cinemas during *Voyager*'s run and all canon sources state that it occurred prior to "Endgame", chronologically.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Not canon at all. Just like the books

Comment: Interestingly, Countdown shows Data as having successfully integrated with B-4's positronic pathways, and being the captain of the U.S.S. Enterprise-E - which is now contradicted by Star Trek: Picard.  While "official", it appears to no longer be "canon"...

Answer (score 3):

Since we now have another *Star Trek* series, I'll go ahead and add this answer:

In *Picard*:

> The Romulans state that, to the collective, the Artifact (damaged Borg Cube) is a graveyard, implying the collective's continued existence. At time of this writing, I've seen up to S1E5, so there maybe more on this subject later.

**After S1E7:**

> Picard continues to speak of the Borg in the present tense, and we see new tech that the Borg assimilated, which featured in a Voyager episode. I read one article (Screen Rant?) that argued that the Queen used it to survive the events of *Endgame* (not the Avengers version!), although how she managed it lying in pieces on the floor is something the article neglects to mention.

Also, the Memory Alpha page for a [spoiler ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shaenor) states that

> It was assimilated sometime in the 2380s, which is at least two years after Voyager's return. The Borg must have lived.

Comment: The Borg Queen managed to "survive" First Contact - I doubt that there's any extra handwaving necessary; after all, Seven of Nine is "Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix *Zero One*", which implies that there are *more* (and not only that, but between 10 and 99 Unimatrices in total...), potentially with their own Queens , or with their own body for an over-spanning Queen mind.  Which also puts a slight twist on both Alice Krige and Susanna Thompson having portrayed the Queen

Comment: @Chronocidal that dosent make sense to me